# Country Specific weather data

Tags: database, csv, weather

So, I am in need to get a daily average of different weather parameters per country.

I'm able to find weather data for different stations within a country, but I would need an average for the complete country. Is there a way to combine the different stations for a country wide average or something like that? Or is there maybe a database available with historical weather data per country?

I need this because i have a dataset which I want to compare to different weather parameters, and my dataset only includes the country as location, not the specific city etc.

I would require data between the year 2012 and 2020, for multiple countries globally.

Kind regards,

Michael

Comment: If you have *n* temperature values, then to get the average you add them all up and divide that sum by *n*.

Comment: Thanks! If I could ask one more thing, Do I need to check for std and outliers when getting the temperature from multiple weather stations to form a country specific average?

Comment: I expect that the average temperature for an area as large as a country is fairly meaningless anyway, but I am not a data analyst.

Comment: Thank you, I see your point.